# Handlebars isn't getting exported?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

## Problem

When executing the compiled handlebars templates the global Handlebars object isn't exported. **NOTE:** the global Backbone object is working.

See, when the code `App.templates.todos` attempts to execute in the `todos.js` file it fails because `App.templates.todos` isn't defined. Well ultimately that's because the third line in the `templates.js` file can't execute because the global `Handlebars` object isn't defined.

Why wouldn't that object get defined? What did I do wrong with require.js here?

**UPDATE:** I've verified that the `handlebars.runtime.js` file is in fact executing **before** the `templates.js` file and so `require.js` is running them in the right order when loading the `todos.js` file.

## Bower Components

```
{
  "name": "todomvc-backbone-requirejs",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "~1.1.0",
    "underscore": "~1.5.0",
    "jquery": "~2.0.0",
    "todomvc-common": "~0.3.0",
    "backbone.localStorage": "~1.1.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.5",
    "requirejs-text": "~2.0.5",
    "handlebars": "~2.0.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "backbone": "~1.1.0"
  }
}
```

## main.js

```
/*global require*/
'use strict';

// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
require.config({
    // The shim config allows us to configure dependencies for
    // scripts that do not call define() to register a module
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        backboneLocalstorage: {
            deps: ['backbone'],
            exports: 'Store'
        },
        handlebars: {
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        },
        templates: {
            deps: ['handlebars'],
            exports: 'App'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        backboneLocalstorage: '../bower_components/backbone.localStorage/backbone.localStorage',
        handlebars: '../bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime',
        templates: '../../../templates',
        text: '../bower_components/requirejs-text/text'
    }
});

require([
    'backbone',
    'views/app',
    'routers/router'
], function (Backbone, AppView, Workspace) {
    /*jshint nonew:false*/
    // Initialize routing and start Backbone.history()
    new Workspace();
    Backbone.history.start();

    // Initialize the application view
    new AppView();
});
```

## todos.js

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'handlebars',
    'templates',
    'common'
], function ($, Backbone, Handlebars, Templates, Common) {
    'use strict';

    var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName:  'li',

        template: App.templates.todos,

        ...
    });

    return TodoView;
});
```

## templates.js

```
this["App"] = this["App"] || {};
this["App"]["templates"] = this["App"]["templates"] || {};
this["App"]["templates"]["stats"] = Handlebars.template({"1":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
```

Answer (score 0):

From [official documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) of RequireJS:

> The shim config only sets up code relationships. To load modules that
>   are part of or use shim config, a normal require/define call is
>   needed. Setting shim by itself does not trigger code to load.

So first you need to somehow call the Handlebars and after try to use it in templates.js.

Comment: So I'm not sure what you mean exactly because the `require` at the top of the `todos.js` does in fact execute the `handlebars.runtime.js` file **before** the `templates.js` file.

Comment: You don't know the order in which require will fetch the modules. Can you try to wrap the templates.js with `define`?

Comment: The `deps` configuration requires `handlebars` to be executed before `templates` right? (I meant for my original comment to be a question)

Comment: Theoretically it should, but it can be not global.

Comment: So I did try loading it in a `define`, like this `define('templates',['handlebars'],function() { ... }`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I think the better solution for you will be just requiring it once in main.js .

Comment: Did you try it? To load it in `main.js` ?